# How do I deserialize this XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How correctly to deserialize XML from my example (look the question in the end)? Am I doing this right? Maybe there is a way to make it easier and more efficient?

XML:

```
<Warehouse>
        <GUID>0d63057d-99e8-11e6-813b-0003ff000011</GUID>
        <Name>WarehouseName</Name>
        <Terms>
            <Term TargetGUID="490ecabf-f011-11e3-b7d9-6c626dc1e098">2</Term>
            <Term TargetGUID="f332d7ff-efd2-11e3-b7d9-6c626dc1e098">4</Term>
        </Terms>
</Warehouse>
```

C#:
Warehouse.cs:

```
[Serializable]
public class Warehouse
{

    [XmlArray("Terms", IsNullable=true)]
    [XmlArrayItem("Term")]
    public WarehouseTransferTerm[] TransferTerms { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
    public string InternalName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

}
```

WarehouseTransferTerm.cs:

```
[Serializable]
public class WarehouseTransferTerm
{

    public Guid SourceWarehouseGuid { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TargetGUID")]
    public Guid TargetWarehouseGuid { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Term")]
    public int TransferTermInDays { get; set; }
}
```

Question: How I can set Warehouse's GUID property value as SourceWarehouseGuid?

Comment: There are four basic classes for serialize/deserialize 1) XML Serialize 2) XmlDocument 3) XDocument 4) XmlReader/XmlWriter.  The best one to use depends on the size of the Xml, the amount of data you need to extract, the number of classes you want to read/write, and the structure of the xml.  You have not given enough requirements to determine "BEST" method.

Comment: @john SourceWarehouseGuid must be Warehouse's GUID property value https://mykmyk.pet/2H5W4w8

Comment: @jdweng OK, how to set Warehouse's GUID property value to SourceWarehouseGuid?

Comment: I suppose you'll have problem with deserializing TransferTermInDays property since it's Value of parent element, not the value of inner XML element 'Term'...

Comment: I updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement custom deserialization logic and just set the value on the dependent items. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
     foreach(var term in TransferTerms)
     {
           term.TargetWarehouseGuid = this.Guid;
     }
}
```

Comment: That's what I need

Answer (score -1):

I like using Dictionaries along with Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> warehouses = doc.Descendants("Warehouse")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("GUID"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XElement warehouse = warehouses["0d63057d-99e8-11e6-813b-0003ff000011"];

            Dictionary<string, XElement> terms = warehouse.Descendants("Term")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("TargetGUID"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string value = terms["490ecabf-f011-11e3-b7d9-6c626dc1e098"].Value;

            warehouse.SetValue(value);

        }
    }
}
```